# How to deal with extensions when splitting workspace into frameworks?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, frameworks

I am working on optimising an iOS project by splitting it into frameworks. I am thinking of separating the UI Components first, but i was puzzled when analysing my approach.
I have Extensions for some of the UIKit components, which i use in my custom components classes and in many other classes outside of my components' group. Now what i thought of first, i could add these extensions to a framework, and import it in my UIComponents and other files in the project, but they can be a lot. Is there a cleaner solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could move the implementation into a framework and keep the customisation in the extension within the app target. For Example:

Before:

```
extension UIViewController {

    // Helper method to show alert
    func showAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "...", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        // ...
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

After:

```
import FrameworkName

extension UIViewController {

    func showAlert() {
        showAlertInFramework(parameters: ParameterTypes)
    }
}
```